# Not able to use property attribute in my meta tag,it say undefined attribute name "property" this is happenining in grails view page

Tags: grails, gsp

```
 '<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->`enter code here`
<html lang="en" >
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
     <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>my system</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta property="og:description" content="description" name="description" />
        <meta content="title" name="title" />
        <meta content="" name="author" />'
```

this is my code where i am using meta tag and property attribute with value as og:description, but my gsp page say undefined attribute name "property".this code i want to use for share on social networking sites.

Comment: michal szule i have posted my code

Comment: and i am not even able use itemprop attribute

Comment: Paste your verbose stacktrace.

Comment: what is that, what do you need actually

Comment: Log with details of an error.

Comment: there is no error, there is a warning in my view page, when check that warning it says undefined attribute name “property” this is happenining in grails view page.

Comment: my application is running but that line of code not getting executed